# Customizing AppearanceEditorPart to allow only Title to be updatable

Tags: c#, web-parts

I am working with Webpart in VS2010. I am trying to see if there is simpler way to extend AppearanceEditorPart so that only Title is visible when the webpart is selected in edit mode

Thanks
CSS

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is easier way to implement the above requirement. All I was trying to do was create an editorpart that would show only the title box so that people can only update the title of the webpart being edited. I figured out that the best alternative is, is to use PropertyGridEditorPart. This webpart is ideal in situation where you want to allow user to set customized property for a webpart. Here is documentation from microsoft website:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.propertygrideditorpart.aspx

In my case i created following property and webpart framework took care of rest!!!!

```
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User),
WebBrowsable,
WebDisplayName("Web part Title"),
WebDescription("Description of property.")]
public string WebPartTitle
{
  get { return this.Title; }
  set { this.Title = value; }
}
```

Thanks